# How can I generate only 3,8 samples from MNIST dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch, sample, mnist

I want to train my model on '3' and '8' samples from MNIST , how can I generate only those samples?

I have tried:

```
 all_train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
 all_train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=all_train_dataset,
                                                batch_size=batch_size,
                                                shuffle=True)
```

And I dont know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the dataset by

```
all_train_dataset = datasets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transform)
selection = torch.logical_or(all_train_dataset.targets == 3, all_train_dataset.targets == 8)
all_train_dataset.data = all_train_dataset.data[selection]
all_train_dataset.targets = all_train_dataset.targets[selection]
```